# Group result mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with array countries values like this. I want to sum the values of the countries.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("54cd5e7804f3b06c3c247428"),
  "country_json": {
     "AE": NumberLong("13"),
     "RU": NumberLong("16"),
     "BA": NumberLong("10"),
     ...
  }
},
{
   "_id": ObjectId("54cd5e7804f3b06c3c247429"),
   "country_json": {
      "RU": NumberLong("12"),
      "ES": NumberLong("28"),
      "DE": NumberLong("16"),
      "AU": NumberLong("44"),
      ...
    } 
 }
```

How to sum the values of countries to get a result like this?

```
{
   "AE": 13,
   "RU": 28,
   ..  
}
```

Comment: `country_json` is not a array as you have mentioned. Do you want to store it as a array of documents or as depicted in the example?

Comment: like it show in the exampe

Answer (score 2):

This can simply be done using [`aggregation`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)

```
> db.test.aggregate([
    {$project: { 
        RU: "$country_json.RU", 
        AE: "$country_json.AE", 
        BA: "$country_json.BA"
    }}, 
    {$group: {
       _id: null, 
       RU: {$sum: "$RU"}, 
       AE: {$sum: "$AE"}, 
       BA: {$sum: "$BA"}
    }
])
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : null, 
    "RU" : NumberLong(28), 
    "AE" : NumberLong(13), 
    "BA" : NumberLong(10) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a very good document structure if you intend to aggregate statistics across the "keys" like this. Not really a fan of "data as key names" anyway, but the main point is it does not "play well" with many MongoDB query forms due to the key names being different everywhere.

Particularly with the aggregation framework, a better form to store the data is within an actual array, like so:

```js
{
    "_id": ObjectId("54cd5e7804f3b06c3c247428"),
    "countries": [
       { "key": "AE", "value": NumberLong("13"),
       { "key": "RU", "value": NumberLong("16"),
       { "key": "BA", "value": NumberLong("10")
    ]
}
```

With that you can simply use the aggregation operations:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$countries" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$countries.key",
        "value": { "$sum": "$countries.value" }
    }}
])
```

Which would give you results like:

```js
{ "_id": "AE", "value": NumberLong(13) },
{ "_id": "RU", "value": NumberLong(28) }
```

That kind of structure does "play well" with the aggregation framework and other MongoDB query patterns because it really is how it's "expected" to be done when you want to use the data in this way.

Without changing the structure of the document you are forced to use JavaScript evaluation methods in order to traverse the keys of your documents because that is the only way to do it with MongoDB:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        var country = this.country_json;
        Object.keys(country).forEach(function(key) {
            emit( key, country[key] );
        });
    },
    function(key,values) {
        return values.reduce(function(p,v) { return NumberLong(p+v) });
    },
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

And that would produce exactly the same result as shown from the aggregation example output, but working with the current document structure. Of course, the use of JavaScript evaluation is not as efficient as the native methods used by the aggregation framework so it's not going to perform as well.

Also note the possible problems here with "large values" in your cast `NumberLong` fields, since the main reason they are represented that way to JavaScipt is that JavaScipt itself has limitations on the size of that value than can be represented. Likely your values are just trivial but simply "cast" that way, but for large enough numbers as per the intent, then the math will simply fail.

So it's generally a good idea to consider changing how you structure this data to make things easier. As a final note, the sort of output you were expecting with all the keys in a single document is similarly counter intuitive, as again it requires traversing keys of a "hash/map" rather than using the natural iterators of arrays or cursors.